# Default app generated successfully but not working

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am new to Sencha Touch and Sencha Command. I downloaded the requisite tools to build a Sencha Touch app. When I use the following command in Sencha Command, the app is generated fine but when I try to access it using the browser I see only the loader.

```
sencha -sdk touch-2.3.1 generate app MyApp ./MyApp
```

When viewed on Firefox, it shows following errors in the console.

```
TypeError: Ext.Loader is undefined bootstrap.js: 7
TypeError: Ext.application is not a function app.js: 50
```

On some investigation, I found that it is looking for the above mentioned files in a directory named touch directly under `http://localhost/`. Whereas I have Sencha framework and my app under `http://localhost/sencha/touch-2.3.1` and `http://localhost/sencha/MyApp`.

Some files under MyApp directory have the path mentioned to touch directory as `../../../../touch`. If I copy the framework in `http://localhost/touch` it works fine.

Why should this happen? Shouldn't my app refer to `http://localhost/sencha/touch-2.3.1` folder for dependencies?

I am using the default configuration to build a default application. Can someone guide me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Cmd assumes that your app runs at the root of the web server... so if you're running it from a subfolder, you might see problems like this.

You can set the correct paths manually to your resources in app.js

```
//at the very top, before Ext.appliction()
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        'Ext' : '../touch',
        'My'  : 'app' //or wherever
    }
});
```

I think that should solve your problem, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for responding arthurakay. I think you understand the problem correctly. I tried the above mentioned approach but it didn't work. I am not sure I understand it correctly. Do I need to mention the path for each and every class in Ext I am going to use in the app?

Comment: No, it would only be for namespaces that differ from anything previously defined.